# Unicode input from a Bluetooth/external keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard, text-input

Is there a way that I can do Unicode character input on an external keyboard on Android 4.4?

For example, on Linux, you hold Ctrl+Shift+U and then start inputting the code point. On Windows and OSX, there's a similar way to do it using a keyboard shortcut.

Is there any way to insert a specific code-point into a text field in Android? (ie: how do I insert U+2022 using an external keyboard on Android?)

Comment: Makes me so sad seeing the exact question I have asked years ago, but no solution. Have you found a solution or workaround?

Comment: Not yet, it's been a while since I've tried though. Maybe Android 5/6 fixed it?

Comment: I have done more digging. Nothing besides some Root hacking from what I can tell. It's a shame :(